# Codeigniter & Datamapper: Retrive all the ID's from ID column and attach to array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, codeigniter-datamapper

I am having trouble collecting all the ids from the ID column. What the code above does is getting only one ID, at least it goes to the array but I want to take all of them.

```
$getArticlesId = new Article_model();
$getArticlesId->select('id');
$getArticlesId->get();
$anarray = $getArticlesId->to_array(array('id'));
```

That returns:
SELECT `articles`.`id`
FROM (`articles`)

and Array ( [id] => 43 ) , but there must be 10 more

What I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

`to_array()` generates an array with your specified field(s). `all_to_array()` generates multiple arrays with your specified id field. `$anarray[0]['id']` should be your first id. Hope this is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
// RETURN ORM OBJECT
    $getArticlesId = new Article_model();
    $getArticlesId->select('id');
    $getArticlesId->get_iterated();
    $getArticlesId_Total = $getArticlesId->result_count();
// -------- EOF - RETURN ORM OBJECT


// GENERATE PHP ARRAY FROM OBJECT
if ($getArticlesId_Total > 1) 
{
    $anarray = $getArticlesId->all_to_array();
}
// -------- EOF - GENERATE PHP ARRAY FROM OBJECT
```

You may also want to try *all_to_single_array()*.
http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/pages/extensions/array.html